# Max of substring - Informix

Tags: sql, substring, informix

I have to ask your help with SQL query for Informix and would really appreciate any comments.

Data for contno field (varchar) looks as follows:

```
C4698  
B0458  
F400221  
D3776  
A0636  
D3787  
B7781  
D13799  
BXXXXX
```

I need to find Maximum value of a number that follows letter in the contno string so tried that:

```
SELECT Max(to_number(contno[2,6]))
FROM informix.customer
WHERE contno[1,1] = "B"
```

...but getting

```
Error: A character to numeric conversion process failed (State:37000, Native Code: FFFFFB43)
```

Also excluding 'BXXXX' values doesn't seem to work. Ahh and tried SUBSTRING function too with the same results.

When skipping max function and running this:

```
SELECT to_number(contno[2,6])
FROM informix.customer
WHERE contno[1,1] = "B"
```

...I get nice list looking like that:

```
4698.0  
458.0  
400221.0  
3776.0  
0636.0  
3787.0  
7781.0  
13799.0
```

... but when trying to ORDER BY getting the same error.

Any idea how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [MATCHES](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1389.htm?lang=en) operator to get only numbers:

```
SELECT  MAX(contno[2,6]::INT)
FROM    customer
WHERE   contno[1,1] = "B"
        AND (
                contno[2,6] MATCHES '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
            OR  contno[2,6] MATCHES '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
            OR  contno[2,6] MATCHES '[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
            OR  contno[2,6] MATCHES '[0-9][0-9]'
            OR  contno[2,6] MATCHES '[0-9]'
        );
```